# Replacing cell data

Tags: jquery

There is a table I am accessing from a remote server, and in this table there is a word "Blah blah". How do I get rid of this or replace it?

I tried the codes below but since I don't know if "Blah blah" is in a table cell, a table row, or a header, etc., I can't seem to get rid of it or replace it:

```
$("tr.header").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Blah blah';}).text('');
$("td.header").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Blah blah';}).text('');
```

"Blah blah" is right in the middle above the table retrieved by document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

demo in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuelbigas/yFwfN/)
js:

```
$("td:contains('Blah blah')").html("HEHE nice");
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Blah blah</td>
        <td>I am coll</td>
        <td>Blah blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>Blah blah</td>
        <td>I am coll</td>
        <td>Blah blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Have not tried your code yet but what if "Blah blah" is not in a table? What if it's just in an HTML outputted by document.getElementById("sometable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;? How do we replace "Blah blah" then?

Answer (score 0):

One approach I think should work is iterating over the `td's` inside your table and setting the text to empty.

```
$('table td').each(function () {
    $(this).text(function (i, v) {
        return v.replace(/Blah blah/g, '');
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/C22mR/1/)**

Comment: Ok thanks will try this soon as I access the server and report back later. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sushanth. Your code does not work. Perhaps "Blah blah" is not in a table? How do we still replace that? It's being pulled from a remote server.